# How to have resources in an iOS framework xcode6 beta

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, xcasset

I'm trying to set up a framework for iOS.  It is a little basic UIFramework and I'd like to to contain fonts and images for buttons and such I'd like to reuse across multiple apps.

Is there anyway to bundle resources in the new frameworks in the xcode6 beta?  I'd hate to have to copy and paste over all the fonts and images every time I want to use the framework.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a halfway solution for now.

I Added a copy files phase to the build phases.  Then all the files I want to be in the framework I add to that build phase.  Then when the frame work is implemented you can drag the resources out of there as references in the project you're using them in.  Then if you update your files and then update the framework the references then point to the new file.

The only down side is it won't keep track of new files added to the framework.

Comment: Did you ever find a full solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample project, which i've found, with a framework containing images
https://github.com/iosweekend-samples/Frameworks-WishList-Example